# Monitoring the replication process on CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, couchbase-lite

I have a project with `CouchDB` and `couchbase-lite` on `Android`.
I have an `Activitiy` ,lets say ReplicationActivity,  where I am showing a `ProgressDialog` while the replication process run, this process uses around 2 hours.
My plan is when the replication process is finished the app moves the user to the MainActivity.
The problem I have is that the app moves to MainActivity before the process is finished, so I have not all the data available on MainActivity

In order to monitoring the replication process I am doing this:

```
CouchbaseManager.getInstance().addProgressListener(new Replication.ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(Replication.ChangeEvent event) {

            if (CouchbaseManager.getInstance().getReplicationProgress() > 0 &&
                    CouchbaseManager.getInstance().getReplicationTotal() > 0 &&
                    CouchbaseManager.getInstance().getReplicationTotal() ==
                    CouchbaseManager.getInstance().getReplicationProgress() &&
                    CouchbaseManager.getInstance().getPullwork().getStatus() !=
                            Replication.ReplicationStatus.REPLICATION_ACTIVE &&
                    CouchbaseManager.getInstance().getPushwork().getStatus() !=
                            Replication.ReplicationStatus.REPLICATION_ACTIVE &&
                    CouchbaseManager.getInstance().getPullmaster().getStatus() !=
                            Replication.ReplicationStatus.REPLICATION_ACTIVE) {
                if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.i("usercontroller", "MOVING TO MAIN ACTIVITY");


                }
```

Any idea about what I can do in order to know the when replication process is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at the `ChangeEvent` object passed to the listener.

Here's an example on how to detect a replication finishing:

```
// Replication.ChangeListener
@Override
public void changed(Replication.ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
  if (changeEvent.getError() != null) {
    Throwable lastError = changeEvent.getError();

    // React to the error

    return;
  }

  if (changeEvent.getTransition() == null) return;

  ReplicationState dest = changeEvent.getTransition().getDestination();

  replicationActive = ((dest == ReplicationState.STOPPING || dest == ReplicationState.STOPPED) ? false : true);

  stateListeners.forEach(listener -> listener.onChange(replicationActive));
}
```

You can find more background and discussion of the code in [this blog](https://blog.couchbase.com/determining-status-replication-couchbase-lite/).